# Why does my SQLite code not work? (CS50 2020 Pset 7 - Movies)

Tags: sqlite, cs50

I've made this SQLite code in the Movies exercise of Pset 7 from CS50 2020. It's the query number 12. The objective is to find all the movies in which both Helena Carter and Johnny Depp acted:

```
SELECT movies.title FROM people
JOIN stars ON stars.person_id = people.id
JOIN movies ON movies.id = stars.movie_id
WHERE movies.id IN (SELECT movies.id FROM movies WHERE name == "Helena Bonham Carter") AND movies.id IN (SELECT movies.id FROM movies WHERE name == "Johnny Depp");
```

But this code doesn't output anything. So I got some hints in Internet and wrote another code, that works correctly:

```
SELECT movies.title FROM people
JOIN stars ON stars.person_id = people.id
JOIN movies ON movies.id = stars.movie_id
WHERE movies.id IN (SELECT movies.id FROM movies WHERE name == "Helena Bonham Carter") AND movies.id IN (
SELECT movies.id FROM people
JOIN stars ON stars.person_id = people.id
JOIN movies ON movies.id = stars.movie_id
WHERE name == "Johnny Depp");
```

I'm still confused. If you take off the second condition of the first code, it works fine, and finds all the movies in which Helena Carter acted. Why did I have to JOIN tables again in order to make a second condition for Johnny Depp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because each `people` row has exactly one name. Therefore this phrase

```
SELECT movies.id FROM movies WHERE name == "Helena Bonham Carter") 
AND movies.id IN (SELECT movies.id FROM movies WHERE name == "Johnny Depp"
```

will never return a result. (As will anything that tries to select `name="a" AND name="b"`)

Comment: So, are the two SELECT statements for Helena and Johnny being executed at the same time? And then is my code comparing the "name" field in each row with both Helena and Johnny names? If that's the case, your answer makes a lot of sense, thank you.

Comment: The code is comparing the `name` column in each row to both names. It always fails (returns no results) no matter the sequence of execution. The subquery in the good version essentially treats `people` as a separate table from the `people` in the "main" query.